# How to Mount my HDD

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Just installed ubuntu on my SSD and reconnected my other HDD, however it shows up in BIOS, but when Ubuntu boots, it isn't showing up in the file system.

**sdb is the SSD**
**sda is a HDD**
**sdc is another HDD**

only the SSD is showing.

Here's some of the output from `sudo fsdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 596.2 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd8000117

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048 1233487871 1233485824 588.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1233489918 1250263039   16773122     8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1233489920 1250263039   16773120     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xabd9c2b1

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048 471623679 471621632 224.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       471625726 488396799  16771074     8G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       471625728 488396799  16771072     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdc: 74.5 GiB, 80026361856 bytes, 156301488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdab2cc78


daniel@daniel-GA-MA785G-UD3H:~$ df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     799M  9.6M  789M   2% /run
/dev/sdb1      ext4      222G  6.0G  205G   3% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G  4.9M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     799M   60K  799M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I added a Screenshot of the disk management GUI I see the gear but the only options are 'Format Partition', 'Edit Partition', 'Create Parition Image', 'Restore Parition Image', and 'Benchmark Parition'.

[Gparted Screenshot of 650GB SATA drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyaXq.png)

[Gparted Screenshot of 250GB SSD drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvXKu.png)

Comment: Could you clarify which `/dev/sdx` is the SSD and which one the HDD. And what is the third disk? Please also add the output of `df -hT` to your question.

Comment: @Thomas Edited my original question to include the information you requested.

Comment: Try to open the Disks application in the GUI, just use the search function. On the left, your partitions should occur. Select your HDD and the little gear should be available to click. Select "Mount Options" -> "Automatic Mount Options" -> "On".

Comment: @Thomas I added what I found at the end of original question.  I didn't see the "Mount Options" selection when I clicked the gearhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Disks app can see all three drives, it sounds like you haven't edited your **/etc/fstab** correctly. In terminal, type **sudo blkid**, and **sudo more /etc/fstab**, and post the output here. Make sure that the uuid's in fstab match what blkid finds. Also assure that no uuid is duplicated. Cheers, Al

Comment: [sudo] password for daniel: 
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="d8000117-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="e970cad8-a691-4c72-bcef-06c858d4be1e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d8000117-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="4a267b26-5c4b-4c13-8da3-9686f8633872" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="abd9c2b1-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="406375bc-2ddb-4925-871e-d9d68c46628d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="abd9c2b1-05"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2014-10-02-00-56-49-00" LABEL="SAMSUNG SSD" TYPE="udf"
/dev/sdc1: PARTUUID="dab2cc78-01"
/dev/sdc5: UUID="43d39e87-6faa-44be-b060-d927d7a2e99b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="dab2cc78-05"

Comment: [sudo] password for daniel: 
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="d8000117-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="e970cad8-a691-4c72-bcef-06c858d4be1e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d8000117-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="4a267b26-5c4b-4c13-8da3-9686f8633872" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="abd9c2b1-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="406375bc-2ddb-4925-871e-d9d68c46628d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="abd9c2b1-05"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2014-10-02-00-56-49-00" LABEL="SAMSUNG SSD" TYPE="udf"
/dev/sdc1: PARTUUID="dab2cc78-01"
/dev/sdc5: UUID="43d39e87-6faa-44be-b060-d927d7a2e99b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="dab2cc78-05"

Comment: You posted the blkid twice, and forgot the /etc/fstab. Either way, your blkid tells me that you have 3 swap files, and possibly nothing else to mount. In terminal, type **swapon**, to see it. Also, along with the fstab, post screenshots of a gparted for each of the drives. I want to see what's on sda1 and sdc1. Lastly, do you have a Samsung CD in your drive? Cheers, Al

Comment: Doh sorry @heynnema.  Long day!  I'll do it tomorrow morning since I have my labtop right now, thanks for helping!  And yes I do have a samsung CD in my drive, it came with the SSD drive I installed.

Comment: **sudo more /etc/fstab command**
daniel@daniel-GA-MA785G-UD3H:~$ sudo more /etc/fstab
[sudo] password for daniel: 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=4a267b26-5c4b-4c13-8da3-9686f8633872 /               ext4    errors=remount
-ro 0       1

Comment: # swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=406375bc-2ddb-4925-871e-d9d68c46628d none            swap    sw            
  0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
`

Comment: **swapon** comamnd :

daniel@daniel-GA-MA785G-UD3H:~$ swapon
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sdb5 partition   8G   0B   -1

Comment: OK, your fstab only shows mount for /root and one swap. There are no other mounts for the other two HDD's. And each of the other HDD's contain swap partitions that should be deleted. I still don't know what's on sda1 and sdc1... if they're mountable partitions, or not. The gparted screenshots should help. Cheers, Al

Comment: Yep thanks heynnema, I'm installing gpartd now..was trying to figure out what gparted was lol, and then if I had it.

Comment: I added the screenshots onto the original questions. But had to delete my other 2 links, since I can only post 2 links, right now.  Also couldn't post a pic of the 70GB drive which also isn't working, but probably the same issue as the 650GB drive.

Comment: OK, your sda and sdc (650 & 80GB) drives have nothing to mount, and aren't in /etc/fstab. You just need to decide how you want to configure your system, format the drives, and (maybe) add mounts for them in /etc/fstab. I'd just format and remove the 80GB drive. Cheers, Al ps: please vote/accept my answer, if you can.